# Compare CSV files in Java with different number of Columns (tokens)

Tags: java, csv

***I have read the other answered/asked questions and none of them handle the question i have***

I have 2 CSV files and I have built a program to compare the files by subtracting the information in `File2` from `File1` to save the results into `File3`. At the moment though I have my program working with just comparing a CSV file with just 1 column to another CSV file with 1 column (CustomerName).

This program works!

**My question is:** Is there a way for me to compare a CSV file with 4 columns to one that has 1 column and have it subtract the difference (like the code I haev now) but not just subtract the difference in column1 but subtract the difference and the corresponding rows it has.

---

To better explain, because I am having a difficult time articulating my question, let me give an example:

Lets say File1.csv contains every customer

```
Customer Phone  Email       Zip
Colt    123456  123@gmail   123456
Mary    321654  123@gmail   123456
John    789654  123@gmail   123456
Trey    987456  123@gmail   123456
```

And lets say File2.csv contains only the ones I wish to delete from File1.csv

```
Customer
Colt
John
```

And what I want is this:

```
Customer Phone  Email       Zip
Mary    321654  123@gmail   123456
Trey    987456  123@gmail   123456
```

So just by knowing the CustomerName I want it to delete not just the name but the corresponding rows as well.

Is this possible?

**For anyone curious this is the code I currently have that works with just the 1 column CSV file.**

---

```
package csvdatacompareapplication;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/* file1 - file2 = file3*/
public class CSVDataCompareApplication {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String path="C:\\Desktop\\";
        String file1="customerListAllCustomers.csv";
        String file2="customerListToRemove.csv";
        String file3="newCustomerList.csv";
        ArrayList<String> arrayList1=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList2=new ArrayList<String>();
        //ArrayList al3=new ArrayList();

        BufferedReader CSVFile1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+file1));
        String dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine();
        while (dataRow1 != null)
        {
            String[] dataArray1 = dataRow1.split(" , ");
            for (String item1:dataArray1)
            { 
               arrayList1.add(item1);
            }

            dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
        }

         CSVFile1.close();

        BufferedReader CSVFile2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+file2));
        String dataRow2 = CSVFile2.readLine();
        while (dataRow2 != null)
        {
            String[] dataArray2 = dataRow2.split(" , ");
            for (String item2:dataArray2)
            { 
               arrayList2.add(item2);

            }
            dataRow2 = CSVFile2.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
        }
         CSVFile2.close();

         for(String bs:arrayList2)
         {
             arrayList1.remove(bs);
         }

         int size=arrayList1.size();
         System.out.println(size);

         try
            {
                FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(path+file3);
                while(size!=0)
                {
                    size--;
                    writer.append(""+arrayList1.get(size));
                    writer.append('\n');
                }
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```